# Return the data-football attribute name

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following piece of code:

```
<button id="btnOne" data-football="Mitre">Press Me</button>
```

How would I get the name of the data tag, so in this case it would be 'data-football'.  I know how I would get the value but would like to know how I can get the name of the data-tag - in this case data-football when the button is pressed.

i.e,

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function(){
   // Get the name of the attribute (data-football - not the value);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean the name of the attribute?

Comment: This really smells like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is your use case for needing to find the name of the attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `attributes` property for getting the all attributes of a HTML tag

```
<div id="_id" data-football='test'></div>
```

```
  <script>
        const attrs = document.getElementById('_id').attributes
        const keyName = attrs[1].nodeName // will be data-football
  </script>
```

Comment: That is perfect.  One other thing is how would I replace the nodeName.  So in this case instead of - <div id="_id" data-football='test'></div> I would change the nodeName data-football to data-rugby='test'

Comment: @Flash20 I'm glad I could help . The `nodeName` property is necessary for getting a specific attribute name .What do you mean about replacing the nodeName ? `attrs` is an array and you can easily log it and find out which index is your goal key for example `data-rugby` I am not sure I understand your intention

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following.

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function(){
       $(this).data('data-football')
    });
```

Or

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnOne", function(){
       $(this).data('data-football')
 });
```

[Read More about jQuery data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)